# Are ABRecordIDs reused after removing a contact and adding another?

Tags: ios, addressbook, abrecord

Does apple reuse the ABRecordID in the AddressBook.framework?

If I remove a record and add a new one? Or are they looping record numbers after advancing through all MAX_INT values and going back to 0?

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to assume either way. The docs only say RecordID will uniquely identify a contact. What do you want to do?

Comment: Unless you find a definitive statement from Apple in the docs, they could change the behavior in the future anyway.

Comment: @Mar0ux I'm trying to determine if specific entries have been modified since the last run of the application. If a delete/add delete/add can't guarantee that new entries wont re-use the identifiers I have to assume my original data is more correct than what is in the address book. or do some kind of integrity check on the two differing records and resolve it myself.